# WPF Scrollviewer inside usercontrol doesn't show vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, prism

I am using PRISM architecture.

I have a structure like below

```
<Window Height="300" Width="300">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl>

      <UserControl>
        <ScrollViewer>
          <StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
       </UserControl>

     </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Horizontal scrollbar shows up but the vertical doesn't.

Please note that changing stackpanel to grid like below doesn't help.

```
          <UserControl>
            <ScrollViewer>
              <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
              </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
          </UserControl>
```

Comment: `I am using PRISM pattern` - PRISM is not a pattern.

Comment: In order for the scrollbar to show you need to constrain the size of the `ScrollViewer` itself, which seems not to be happening here.

Comment: @HighCore Is it possible to bind the height of window to scrollviewer? If yes, please show me how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. See [Rohit's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20889057/643085)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid`. This helps the `ScrollViewer` to use the available space within `Grid` and if content overflows, it will show scrollbars. It depends on where you use your `UserControl` though. Make sure this `UserControl` is not placed inside a `ScrollViewer` or any scrollable control.

```
      <UserControl>
        <Grid>
          <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
      </UserControl>
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. Scrollbar is still not visible.

Comment: Make sure your `UserControl` is NOT placed inside a scrollable control and its alignment is in stretched state.

Comment: I have shown the entire xaml. Usercontrol is inside itemscontrol which is inside a root grid.

Comment: `ItemsPanel` of `ItemsControl` is a `StackPanel` by default. Do you really want scrollbars for each item in `ItemsControl`? Otherwise you can remove the `ScrollViewer` from `UserControl` and instead wrap the ItemsControl inside one.

Comment: Actually there would be only 1 usercontrol at a time in ItemsControl. Least for this view. I want Scrollbar visibility auto for both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: You can remove the `ScrollViewer` from the `UserControl` then. Wrap the `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

`StackPanel` grows on indefinitely (i.e. height is not restricted until you fix it be setting explicitly).

Either **use another panel** say *Grid, DockPanel* etc. or constrain fix height for your StackPanel.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

OR

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Height="300">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can also constrain height like this:

```
<StackPanel Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: You have again place StackPanel inside Grid. Size still not restricted.

Comment: Don't items inside grid expand and occupy all the available space?

Comment: You can restrict `StackPanel` height by binding it to Window height. See update in my answer.

Comment: Can I bind ActualHeight of Window using a viewmodel property? Some of the controls are not visible and hence, I will have to change the actual height.

Comment: You can bind Height to ViewModel property but not ActualHeight since its readonly property.

Comment: Can you show me an example of accessing the mainwindow property in usercontrol viewmodel?

Comment: `Height="{Binding PropertyName}"` will work if you have set DataContext for window correctly.

Comment: It would be usercontrol viewmodel not viewmodel of window. Can I access window's height using relativesource?

Comment: Ofcourse you can like i mentioned in my answer using `RelativeSource`.

Comment: Can I access Window's height inside usercontrol viewmodel/datacontext using something like Relative Source or can it be done only in xaml? Please show me how to do it in viewmodel.

Comment: In Viewmodel you should not access any UI element. And yeah RelativeSource is for XAML only. Why you want to do that?

Comment: Some of the controls are not visible and hence, I will have to reduce the height

Comment: But you have ScrollViewer in place for that. User can scroll down to item.

Comment: Its not visible I don't know why.

Comment: Sorry but no one will be able to help without seeing your code. Atleast try producing it in small sample code and post it here so that we can look at it.